# Bootstrap dropdowns menu clipped by div with overflow-x: scroll

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu

I know that this subject is recurrent, however, I used several suggestions found in 'stackoverflow' but none of them got the expected result.

Basically I need a table inside a container (div for example), that I can scroll horizontally, since there may be more elements (columns).

A solution was using jQuery to increase the height of the container by clicking the button of dropdown, but particularly, I consider ugly this alternative.

```
.table-outter {
overflow-x: scroll; 
overflow-y: hidden; 
width: 100%; }

<div class="table-outter">
<table class="table table-hover table-condensed" style="width: 1200px;">
...

        // FIT HEIGHT DIV
        var a = $('.table-outter').height();
        $('.dropdown-toggle').click(function() {
            var open = $(this).parent().hasClass('open');
            $('.table-outter').height((a));
            var b = $(this).siblings('.dropdown-menu').height();
            if(!open) { $('.table-outter').height((a+b)); }
            $("ul.nxw-dropdown li a").click(function() { 
                $('.table-outter').height((a)); 
            });
        });
```

**Current**:
[image: Bootstrap dropdowns menu clipped]

**Desired**:
[image: Desired]

**With jQuery**:
[image]

Comment: a fiddle would be nice.. ;)